# SQlite UPDATE WHERE Syntax Error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-update, syntax-error

I have this code with 2 entry boxes in tkinter which are passed through a database. I am trying to create and update query which updates the record in the database however I do not know how to create this from entry boxes. I have already researched this error. Exercise and Weight are the two entry boxes with MemberID being used to identify which record to update. This is the code

```
        cursor.execute('''

        UPDATE Exercises
        SET (Exercise =?, Weight = ?)
        WHERE MemberID=? ;


    ''')
```

The error is `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`

Comment: Please don't change your code after someone has posted an answer. This leads to confusion

Answer (score 2):

The `set` clause shouldn't be surrounded with parenthesis, just remove them and you should be OK:

```
UPDATE Exercises
SET    Exercise = ?, Weight = ?
WHERE  MemberID = ?;
```

Comment: That creates an error `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 0 supplied.`

Comment: @JohnMcNulty Well, you are using `?` so you should provide the arguments to `execute`. How should `sqlite` know what to replace `?` with? Read how parameterized queries work

Comment: I have now edited the question to include more code.